# Android - Firebase Performance does not measure screen performance for fragments

Tags: android, firebase-performance

I have added Firebase Performance (v. 20.1.1) to my native single-activity Android app. From what I've read since 20.1.0 there is out-of-the-box support for measuring screen performance for fragments (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#performance_v20-1-0). In the console however I only see data for my activity. I am using jetpack's navigation to handle fragments, but also tried making framgent transactions manually with the same result. Is there something else I need to do in order to see data for fragments? I followed this instruction https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android?hl=en#kotlin+ktx
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming across this issue - reinstalling application after configuring Firebase Performance solved the problem

Comment: Always spend hours until one notices that restarting may do the trick. Thank you!